# Multiple DatagridViews C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, behavior

I have 3 DataGridViews in a form in C#. I configured one datagridview than copy+paste the other two. They got the same datatable as datasource. The problem is that when I click on a cell in any datagridview the selected row is changing in the other two. How can I delete this beahviour?

Comment: copy the data source 3 times. if it is `DataTable`, then use `Copy` method.

Comment: Change the eventhandler method name for all the DataGridViews. All should be with different names.

Comment: You should set datasource of each datagridview to different datatable. 
If dt is a datatable that every gridview is using then you can create new datatable by dt1 = dt.Copy() then assign dt1 as datasource to other gridview

Comment: With something like Datatable dt1=dt it did not worked, but it worked with copy(). Thanks

Comment: `dt1=dt` will only copy the reference. Both objects will still refer to the same entity in memory. This is why changing the one has changed the other

Comment: You should indirect the datasource by inserting bindingsources, which are based on the datatable!

Comment: @MongZhu but why it affected only the row and the column was not affected?